# Mono for Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I need to develop .net code on mac os x 10.9.2

I heard about Mono and downloaded Xamarin studio and running it asks for downloading Mono framework. 
This is the page it leads me to:
http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

For the latest version 3.4.0 :

```
Binaries for Mono 3.0 are currently available as a beta release
    Includes Mono and Gtk#. Installs in /Library/Frameworks:
The MDK package is for developers.
Mono 3.4.0
Intel: Mono MRE installer | Mono MDK installer
```

Both the Mono MRE and Mono MDK installer seem to be missing links. Any help with it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still get the 3.4 its just the link which is wrong.
If you go to this link you will get the proper links for the MDK and MRE
http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.4.0/macos-10-x86/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't go with this alternative though. I went for parallel desktop instead.